# Why does the price of a TIPS bond not match the inflation adjusted principal near or at maturity?

Tags: united-states, bonds, inflation, government-bonds, tips

As stated by the US Treasury:

> With a rise in the index, or inflation, the principal increases. With a fall in the index, or deflation, the principal decreases.

I'm curious why a TIPS ([912828QV5](https://www.treasurydirect.gov/instit/annceresult/tipscpi/tipscpi_detail.htm?cusip=912828QV5)) bond maturing on **07/15/2021** (in 2 months) is priced at **$101.22**, when the index ratio is **1.18456**. Isn't this bond going to be paying out **$118.56** at maturity? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

TIPS are quoted as a percentage of the *real* (inflation-adjusted) principal, which is probably slightly less than 118.56 with 2 months to go. So you're paying 101.22% of *that* amount (plus any accrued interest) and will get ~118.56 + 0.625% * 118.56 at maturity.